# How to get the intersection area of two same circles?

Tags: integration

If two same circles intersect, how to get the intersection area?
(Like this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkSOy.jpg))

I saw a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573106/simplification-of-ratio-of-intersection-area-of-two-circles-to-area-of-circles). It said that is impossible, but I don’t think so. Please every pros help.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: In the post you link they give a general formula for two circles of radius $r$ and $R$. Since you want two _same_ circles, taking $r=R$ in the formula given in the post gives a simplification as it's a special case. You can verify this by calculating the area as the integral $4 \int_0^{r-d} \sqrt{r^2-(x+d)^2}\, \mathrm{d}x$ where $2(r-d)$ is the width of the overlap and $r$ the radius of both circles.

Comment: I am trying that method